# How to guarantee message order in RabbitMQ (or any other asynchronous message queue service)

Tags: rabbitmq, message-queue

I have a Java application which publishes events to RabbitMQ. It has one very important characteristic: message order must be preserved at all times. The consumer can handle duplicates, but it cannot handle when message `2` is enqueued before message `1`, so to say.

I have been reading a lot about RabbitMQ lately, and I feel there is only solution to do this: set the channel in `confirm` mode (https://www.rabbitmq.com/confirms.html - basically, it forces the broker to acknowledge the publication) and publish one by one. With one by one I mean that the message `2` is only published after RabbitMQ confirmed (via an asynchronous `ACK` response) that message `1` is actually well received and persisted.

I tried this in a conceptual implementation, and while this works fine, it's uber slow, without exaggerating. Which makes sense: after all, we are now limiting our message rate to 1 message at a time.

So this leads me to my question: are there other, more performant, ways to ensure that message ordering is always preserved (either in RabbitMQ or via different approaches)?

Although my concern is RabbitMQ, I believe this question might be applied to any kind of asynchronous message queue service.

Answer (score 2):

RabbitMQ's clients **enqueue in the same order that you sent**. It's when subscribers go down, you get network splits or the subscriber NACKs messages that they can get re-ordered; and even then **RMQ tries to keep them in the same approximate order by re-queueing at the same position**, or as close to the same position.

You can do it like you suggest; **take one message at a time**, because if you take a message, but crash before you've ACKed it from the broker, it will pop up when your service comes back up, at the same position.

This assumes you only have a **single service instance at any given time**, consuming from the queue. Which in turn is a distributed systems problem on its own, if you have a scheduler like Kubernetes or Mesos, spawning your service instances.

Another solution would be to ensure ordering of processing in the receiving service, by "resequencing" the messages based on their logical timestamps/sequence numbers.

I've written a much more thorough guide as annotated code here https://github.com/haf/rmq-publisher-confirms-hopac/blob/master/src/Server/Shared/RabbitMQ.fs — with batching you can resequence. Furthermore, if your idempotence builds the consecutive sequence numbers into its logic, you can start taking batches and each event will be idempotent, despite being re-consumed.